# Shared Hosting Triggering CORS with same domain and port

Tags: laravel, apache, cors, shared-hosting, preflight

A have been struggling for the last couple of days with CORS, specifically preflight requests in a non-CORS setup. **I'm sending a request** from a SPA app via axios (domain.com:80) to a rest API (domain.com:80/api) **and its getting classified as a CORS request. Locally, with the same setup, requests are fine, not triggering preflight ones**.

In my research a same origin request must have:

- same domain
- same subdomain
- same port
- same protocol

I think my production environment checks all of the above but something says the opposite.

My environment is hosted in a shared-host provider in the following maner:

SPA (Vue)     - http:/domain:80/company-name/
API (Laravel) - http:/domain:80/company-name/api

I have already tried:

- Clonning the environment locally (Works fine - does not send preflight requests)
- Enable / Disable Access-Control-Allow-Headers
- To be honest i don't even know what to try next :|

Solving this problem will make my app 100% faster so is kind of a big deal for me. But it simply doesn't make sense. Maybe i'm missing something obvious.

Maybe could be some proxy related thing that my shared-hosting provider is doing. But even than i wouldn't know how to check that.

### Preflight Request Example (From network tab in Dev Tools):

> **General**
>   Request URL: http:/domain/company-name/api/perfil/3
>   Request Method: **OPTIONS**
>   Status Code: 200 OK
>   Remote Address: **185.200.153.100:80**
>   Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
>
> **Response Headers**
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers: AUTHORIZATION
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http:/domain
>   Access-Control-Max-Age: 25200
>   Cache-Control: no-cache, private
>   Connection: close
>   Content-Length: 0
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   Date: Sat, 27 Apr 2019 18:28:40 GMT
>   Server: Apache
>
> **Request Headers**
>   Provisional headers are shown
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
>   Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
>   Origin: http:/domain
>   Referer: http:/domain/company-name/perfis
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36

### Request Example (Right after preflight response):

> **General**
>   Request URL: http:/domain/company-name/api/perfil/3
>   Request Method: GET
>   Status Code: 200 OK
>   Remote Address: **185.200.153.100:80**
>   Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
>
> **Response Headers**
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http:/domain
>   Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *
>   Age: 0
>   Cache-Control: no-cache, private
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   Date: Sat, 27 Apr 2019 18:28:41 GMT
>   Server: Apache
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Vary: Origin,Authorization
>   Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
>   X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
>   X-RateLimit-Remaining: 58
>   X-Varnish: 46418125
>
> **Request Headers**
>   Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
>   Authorization: Bearer {token}
>   Origin: http:/domain
>   Referer: http:/domain/company-name/perfis
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36

### domain/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^(api)($|/) - [L]
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css|woff2)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

### domain/api/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If any other data is needed feel free to ask.

Comment: What's the exact error message that the browser is logging in the devtools console? The request headers shown in the question don't indicate any errors; instead they indicate your server is sending back Access-Control-Allow-\* headers that you've configured it to send.

Comment: @sideshowbarker there is no error, its just the existence of preflight requests in this environment, that doesn't make sense. For me, sending a request from domain.com to domain.com/api shouldn't trigger any preflight requests.

Comment: Since you’re not showing the real URLs in the error messages in the question, there’s no way for anybody else here to get you any help. But if your browser is making a preflight OPTIONS request then in fact your frontend code is trying to make a cross-origin request. So the URL you’re sending the request to is not at the same origin as your frontend code.

Comment: @sideshowbarker those aren't errors, i simply copy and paste then from the network tab in chrome dev tools. I'm sorry but i can't share the real urls and ips... How can i check the origin from both codebases?  I'm assuming the remote addresses have to be the same right?

Comment: As far as checking the URLs, the 'domain' part must be exactly the same. So for example 'api.domain.com' and 'www.domain.com' are two different origins. The headers you copied from the Network tab show 'Origin: http:/domain' and 'http:/domain/company-name/api/perfil/3'. So what I am telling you is that the origin of whatever the real 'http:/domain/company-name/api/perfil/3' URL actually is does not exactly match whatever 'Origin: http:/domain' actually is. Either the 'domain' part is not exactly the same, or they are not both 'http' or both 'https', or there is some port number you elided.

Comment: In other words, the response headers indicate your frontend code is at 'http:/domain/company-name/perfis' and your code is making a request to 'http:/domain/company-name/api/perfil/3'. But actually the the real 'http:/domain' parts of those URLs do actually match exactly. If they did match exactly, your browser wouldn’t be sending an Origin header in the request and wouldn’t be making a preflight OPTIONS call.

Comment: As far as your question *“How can i check the origin from both codebases”*?, open browser devtools and paste `document.defaultView.location.origin` into the console.

Comment: As far as your question, *“I'm assuming the remote addresses have to be the same”* the answer is that for the purposes of determining the origin, the remote address irrelevant as far as the browser is concerned. The browser doesn’t check that. But even if it the remote address is exactly the same, that’s not sufficient to make the URLs same-origin — because, for example, you could be using virtual hosting in your web server such that the web server is managing multiple hosts at the same IP address. e.g., you have api.domain.com and www.domain.com with the same IP address.

Comment: @sideshowbarker thanks so so much for your patience! I had conviced me that both  URLs were equal but i was simply blind for the fact that one had www. and the other hadn't. I had no idea that the www. prefix would cause me so much trouble one day. In this modern days we take for granted the missing www. but it has its consequences. **CASE CLOSED**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Maybe i'm missing something obvious.*

Yep.

In the SPA i was fetching `domain/api` when indeed `www.domain/api` was the rigth one. Making the origin URL match the request URL, as explained by @sideshowbarker

> As far as checking the URLs, the 'domain' part must be exactly the same. So for example 'api.domain.com' and 'www.domain.com' are two different origins. The headers you copied from the Network tab show 'Origin: http:/domain' and 'http:/domain/company-name/api/perfil/3'. So what I am telling you is that the origin of whatever the real 'http:/domain/company-name/api/perfil/3' URL actually is does not exactly match whatever 'Origin: http:/domain' actually is. Either the 'domain' part is not exactly the same, or they are not both 'http' or both 'https', or there is some port number you elided.